# Bad Cycles in Interaction Nets

Tags: recursion, interaction-nets

Could someone explain to me the following quote from [Interaction Nets 1991 paper by Simon Gay](https://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/%7Esimon/publications/diploma.pdf). To be specific, what are bad cycles and how connected ports in the same partition eliminates them?

> The solution is to divide the ports of each agent into partitions
> which are used in the following way. If a net is built up from the
> empty net by successively adding agents, which may or may not be
> connected to existing agents, then at any time the net consists of a
> number of connected components. Connecting two or more ports of a new
> agent to a single component forms a cycle in the net. The rule is that
> this can only be done if all the ports being connected to the same
> component are in the same partition. This guarantees that nets
> containing bad cycles cannot be constructed; and, since the same
> constraint applies to the net on the right hand side of an interaction
> rule, that no bad cycles can be introduced by reductions.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to ask a more specific question and clarify what you are asking?  "I cannot fully get..." is not a question.  I'm not sure what you mean by "what kind..." or what it means to "element" a cycle.  It might help to tell us what you *do* understand and summarize the main ideas of the paper as you do understand them.

Comment: @D.W. Hi and thx for passing by. I have added more specific questions in my edit. Hopefully, someone can help me answering them.

Comment: I am not sure I'll find the time to write an answer (sorry!), but you should look at Lafont's original paper (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/96709.96718), it defines everything formally and is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the paper:

> It is possible to define rules which lead to non-terminating computations, [...] but further constraints on nets can ensure that when a sequence of reductions terminates, the result can be interpreted as a meaningful answer rather than a deadlock situation.

and:

> But if the net contains cycles, the situation is a deadlock, and it is these cases which should be eliminated.

The goal is apparently to avoid deadlock.  Thus, my reading is that the design seeks to find a way to prevent construction of cycles that could cause deadlock.

Comment: Hi again. To understand bad cycles better, what is the difference between these cycles: "However, it is possible to distinguish between innocuous and pathological cycles"? What happens when it is say a deadlock that is different than when it is not?

Comment: Also, I would like someone to explain this solution to me and why it works: "The solution is to divide the ports of each agent into partitions which are used in the following way. If a net is built up from the empty net by successively adding agents, which may or may not be connected to existing agents, then at any time the net consists of a number of connected components. Connecting two or more ports of a new agent to a single component forms a cycle in the net. The rule is that this can only be done if all the ports being connected to the same component are in the same partition."